# Is there a Safari extension to provide a drop-down menu listing all tabs, or shows all tabs in the tab bar?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

Safari used to have a dropdown on the right-hand side of the tab bar listing tabs. In Safari 9, that's gone, and instead all tabs are present in the tab bar, with many being almost or completely obscured. It seems to keep a few visible and then the ones on both sides are compressed or "behind" others. (From a UI point of view, this is very frustrating and makes clicking to select a tab very difficult.)

Is there an extension that provides either:

- A drop-down menu listing all tabs, so that clicking it will show that tab
- All tabs are always shown on the tab bar, and their size shrinks as more are opened? (This matches Chrome's behaviour.)

There used to be extensions to do the first in the Safari 5/6 era, but the ones I googled for haven't been updated since. Ideally, though, I'd prefer to copy Chrome's behaviour - it is useable and clear.

Comment: Don't know of any extensions (though it'd be pretty easy to write one), but do you know about the 'Show All Tabs' toolbar button that's been around since Safari 7 or so, which zooms out to show you all your open tabs and allows you to click one to switch to it? (You can also use the 'zoom out' pinch gesture, if you have it set up.)

Comment: I do know, thanks. It's pretty much the opposite of what I want to have - I would like to have all tabs on the tab bar. To use that, you have to zoom out, scroll, find your tabs y what it looks like (not page name), click to zoom in. It's pretty but inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

[The TabList extension](http://nickvdp.com/tablist/) provides a dropdown list of open tabs (also recently closed ones).